# tensorflow on GPU: no known devices, despite cuda's deviceQuery returning a "PASS" result

Tags: tensorflow

> Note : this question was initially [asked on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7648#issuecomment-280866214), but it was asked to be here instead

I'm having trouble running tensorflow on gpu, and it does not seems to be the usual cuda's configuration problem, because everything seems to indicate cuda is properly setup.

The main symptom: when running tensorflow, my gpu is not detected ([the code being run](https://gist.github.com/oelmekki/cafda411bf5c2ea695d984fa98e0995b), and [its output](https://gist.github.com/oelmekki/77235c6b0dde99b3438f190eb557f40f)).

What differs from usual issues is that cuda seems properly installed and running `./deviceQuery` from cuda samples is successful ([output](https://gist.github.com/oelmekki/fe65a15daec45aa90ec33b10b51d3aae)).

I have two graphical cards:

- an old GTX 650 used for my monitors (I don't want to use that one with tensorflow)
- a GTX 1060 that I want to dedicate to tensorflow

I use:

- [tensorflow-1.0.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow)
- cuda-8.0 ([ls -l /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcud*](https://gist.github.com/oelmekki/6e5e9d7d1ea871e1d73efae307efe9ce))
- cudnn-5.1.10
- python-2.7.12
- nvidia-drivers-375.26 (this was installed by cuda and replaced my distro driver package)

I've tried:

- adding `/usr/local/cuda/bin/` to `$PATH`
- forcing gpu placement in tensorflow script using `with tf.device('/gpu:1'):` (and `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):` when it failed, for good measure)
- whitelisting the gpu I wanted to use with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`, in case the presence of my old unsupported card did cause problems
- running the script with sudo (because why not)

Here are the outputs of [nvidia-smi](https://gist.github.com/oelmekki/7bdcb5cc2f791cea561a60f8b21e87b5) and [nvidia-debugdump -l](https://gist.github.com/oelmekki/b83a5a0a72e8924aeb44b70b3598f9b4), in case it's useful.

At this point, I feel like I have followed all the breadcrumbs and have no idea what I could try else. I'm not even sure if I'm contemplating a bug or a configuration problem. Any advice about how to debug this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Update**: with the help of Yaroslav on github, I gathered more debugging info by raising log level, but it doesn't seem to say much about the device selection : https://gist.github.com/oelmekki/760a37ca50bf58d4f03f46d104b798bb

**Update 2**: Using theano detects gpu correctly, but interestingly it complains about cuDNN being too recent, then fallback to cpu ([code ran](https://gist.github.com/oelmekki/34b6e41a0ff2b17ff9f39bcf56d0635a), [output](https://gist.github.com/oelmekki/11626d6b34058337dae64f1915e5a9fe)). Maybe that could be the problem with tensorflow as well?

Comment: as another sanity check you could try another framework (like Theano) with GPU to see if it works, perhaps your GPU setup is somehow broken that's not detected by deviceQuery

Comment: Good idea, thanks. I'll try that and report it in the question body.

Comment: that output is suspiciously small, here's what I see when I run with VLOG=1 -- http://pastebin.com/LQF0j3Ri

Comment: Yep, I've truncated it past the device selection, as the rest is probably irrelevant. Here is the full log : https://gist.github.com/oelmekki/25ea3b1186c2ee7aaa23448547bc23b2

Answer (score 80, accepted):

From the log output, it looks like you are running the CPU version of TensorFlow (PyPI: [`tensorflow`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow)), and not the GPU version (PyPI: [`tensorflow-gpu`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow-gpu)). Running the GPU version would either log information about the CUDA libraries, or an error if it failed to load them or open the driver.

If you run the following commands, you should be able to use the GPU in  subsequent runs:

```
$ pip uninstall tensorflow
$ pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: Oh, indeed. I followed this doc [1] while tensorflow was already installed, I wasn't aware it needed an other package. Thanks! -- [1] https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu

Comment: Whenever I install tensorflow-gpu, it will reinstall tensorflow. Is this supposed to happen? I can't get it to detect my devices..

Comment: I have the same issue, and I follow your steps, "uninstall tensorlow" and "install tensorflow-gpu" I got this error : 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Session'

Comment: Hallelujah, I've been beating my brains against getting my laptop GeForce 940MX working and the uninstall above worked. Would never have thought to try that.

Comment: This answer is most likely deprecated in 2021.. any other solutions?

Comment: This did not work for me when trying to install tensorflow-gpu=1.14.0. Same behavior as with cpu

Comment: did not work either for me, nor any of the variations from below answers

Comment: This is depricated!

Answer (score 28):

None of the other answers here worked for me. After a bit of tinkering I found that this fixed my issues when dealing with Tensorflow built from binary:

---

**Step 0: Uninstall protobuf**

```
pip uninstall protobuf
```

**Step 1: Uninstall tensorflow**

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
```

**Step 2: Force reinstall Tensorflow with GPU support**

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow-gpu
```

**Step 3: If you haven't already, set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES**

So for me with 2 GPUs it would be

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1
```

Comment: you save my day !

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 18):

In my case:

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow
```

is not enough. Because when reinstall with:

```
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu
```

It is still reinstall tensorflow with cpu not gpu.
So, before install tensorflow-gpu, I tried to remove all related tensor folders in site-packages uninstall protobuf, and it works!

For conclusion:

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow
```

Remove all tensor folders in ~\Python35\Lib\site-packages

```
pip3 uninstall protobuf
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: Typo suggestion : I suggest you use `pip3` everywhere, in your post. 

In my case, i removed tensorboard, and tensorflow-1.3.0.dist-info from dist-packages and it unblocked this issue.

Answer (score 9):

Might seem dumb but a `sudo reboot` has fixed the exact same problem for me and a couple others.

Comment: Rebooting was all I needed too. ^^

Comment: saved my day ^_^

Answer (score 2):

The answer that saved my day came from Mark Sonn. Simply add this to `.bashrc` and
`source ~/.bashrc` if you are on Linux:

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1
```

Previously I had to use this workaround to get tensorflow recognize my GPU:

```
import tensorflow as tf

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices(device_type="GPU")
tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(devices=gpus[0], device_type="GPU")
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(device=gpus[0], enable=True)
```

Even though the code still worked, adding these lines every time is clearly not something I would want.
My version of `tensorflow` was built from source according to [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) to get v2.3 support CUDA 10.2 and cudnn 7.6.5.

If anyone having trouble with that, I suggest doing a quick skim over the docs. Took 1.5 hours to build with bazel. Make sure you have gcc7 and bazel installed.

Answer (score 0):

This error may be caused by your GPU's compute capability, CUDA officially supports GPU's compute capability within 3.5 ~ 5.0, you can check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA

In my case, the error was like this:

> Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 640M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 3.0) with Cuda compute capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5.

For now we can only compile from source code on Linux (or mac OS) to break the '3.5~5.0' limit.

Answer (score 0):

There are various system incompatible problems.

The requirement for libraries can vary from the version of TensorFlow.

During using python in interactive mode a lot of useful information is printing into **stderr**. What I suggest for TensorFlow with version 2.0 or more to call:

> python3.8 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print('tf version:', tf.**version**); tf.config.list_physical_devices()"

After this command, you will observe missing libraries (or a version of it) for work with GPU in addition to requirements:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements
- https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#hardware_requirements

p.s. CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES should not have a real connection with TensorFlow, or it's more general - it's a way to customize available GPUs for all launched processes.

Answer (score 0):

**For anaconda users**. I installed `tensorflow-gpu` via GUI using Anaconda Navigator and configured NVIDIA GPU as in [tensorflow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu?hl=en) but tensorflow couldn't find the GPU anyway. Then I uninstalled tensorflow, always via GUI (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54292936/11764049)) and reinstalled it via command line in an anaconda prompt issuing:

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```

and then tensorflow could find the GPU correctly.