# Uninstalling TensorFlow from Anaconda environment

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, conda

Does anyone know how to uninstall TensorFlow from Anaconda environment? I want to upgrade the TensorFlow to the latest version  which is ver.1.4, but not working well. So I want to uninstall it and then install the newest version.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can remove a package with the `conda remove` command. So for TensorFlow this would be `conda remove tensorflow`.

Answer (score 21):

If you have installed using pip then use:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

Answer (score 8):

The following helped me to completely remove Tensorflow after I used `conda remove tensorflow` and  `pip uninstall tensorflow`

```
python3 -m pip uninstall protobuf 
python3 -m pip uninstall tensorflow   
python3 -m pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
```

Answer (score 2):

How to remove packages from Anaconda environment

Step 1:open anaconda navigator and select environment from which package you want to uninstall

Step 2:left click on the rectangular box and select mark for removal and finally click apply button

[image: open anaconda navigator and select environment from which package you want to uninstall]

[image: left click on the rectangular box and select mark for removal and finally click apply button]

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily uninstall by 
`conda uninstall tensorflow`
from Anaconda