# ubuntu 16.04 tensorflow-gpu Device mapping: no known devices

Tags: python, tensorflow

testgpu.py has :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import h5py
import numpy as np
import scipy

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

python testgpu.py

```
/home/vivek/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
2018-02-18 20:15:01.831898: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-02-18 20:15:01.939073: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:895] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-02-18 20:15:01.939557: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1105] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Quadro M1000M major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.0715
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 1.96GiB freeMemory: 1.59GiB
2018-02-18 20:15:01.939593: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1195] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: Quadro M1000M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: Quadro M1000M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0
2018-02-18 20:17:18.736555: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:297] Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: Quadro M1000M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0
```

Doing same thing again give :

```
vivek@vivek:~$ python testgpu.py 
/home/vivek/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
2018-02-18 20:22:46.350797: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-02-18 20:22:46.358998: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:168] Internal: failed initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal 0: Internal: failed call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testgpu.py", line 7, in <module>
    sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
  File "/home/vivek/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1509, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/home/vivek/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 628, in __init__
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewDeprecatedSession(opts, status)
  File "/home/vivek/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.
```

And doing it yet again gives:

```
vivek@vivek:~$ python testgpu.py 
/home/vivek/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
2018-02-18 20:24:30.562864: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-02-18 20:24:30.563991: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:406] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN
2018-02-18 20:24:30.564037: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:158] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: vivek
2018-02-18 20:24:30.564044: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: vivek
2018-02-18 20:24:30.564094: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] libcuda reported version is: 390.25.0
2018-02-18 20:24:30.564185: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:369] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  390.25  Wed Jan 24 20:02:43 PST 2018
GCC version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6) 
"""
2018-02-18 20:24:30.564200: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:193] kernel reported version is: 390.25.0
2018-02-18 20:24:30.564206: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:300] kernel version seems to match DSO: 390.25.0
Device mapping: no known devices.
2018-02-18 20:24:30.564475: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:297] Device mapping:
```

As you can see from the output, the first time , it shows my gpu being present, 
the second time around it shows some other error and finally the third time it shows device mapping : no known devices.

How do I fix this inconsistency .

My other details are as follows :

````
```vivek@vivek:~$ nvidia-smi 
Sun Feb 18 20:29:55 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.25                 Driver Version: 390.25                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro M1000M       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   40C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    346MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1157      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           178MiB |
|    0      1652      G   compiz                                        44MiB |
|    0      5237      G   ...-token=AD08A16340548442F3BB1D30639D9BA2   118MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
vivek@vivek:~$ 
```
````

and the nvcc shows  :

```
vivek@vivek:~$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:03_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176
vivek@vivek:~$
```

Tensorflow-gpu alone is installed :

```
vivek@vivek:~$ pip list | grep tensor
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
tensorflow-gpu (1.5.0)
tensorflow-tensorboard (1.5.1)
vivek@vivek:~$
```

and this is the other output :

```
vivek@vivek:~$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  390.25  Wed Jan 24 20:02:43 PST 2018
GCC version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6) 
vivek@vivek:~$
```

I have followed this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42652258/4932791

However after make and ./deviceQuery ; the result is a fail with the following message.

```
vivek@vivek:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery$ ./deviceQuery 
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 30
-> unknown error
Result = FAIL
```

I replaced my code with the code from tensorflow website and upon running it got this result :
code in testgpu.py:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import h5py
import numpy as np
import scipy

a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(c))
```

which gives the following results:

```
    python testgpu.py 
/home/vivek/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
2018-02-18 20:47:28.780480: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-02-18 20:47:28.781788: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:406] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN
2018-02-18 20:47:28.781837: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:158] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: vivek
2018-02-18 20:47:28.781862: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: vivek
2018-02-18 20:47:28.781925: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] libcuda reported version is: 390.25.0
2018-02-18 20:47:28.781986: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:369] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  390.25  Wed Jan 24 20:02:43 PST 2018
GCC version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6) 
"""
2018-02-18 20:47:28.782021: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:193] kernel reported version is: 390.25.0
2018-02-18 20:47:28.782028: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:300] kernel version seems to match DSO: 390.25.0
Device mapping: no known devices.
2018-02-18 20:47:28.782403: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:297] Device mapping:

MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-02-18 20:47:28.782962: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:874] MatMul: (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
b: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-02-18 20:47:28.782996: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:874] b: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
a: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-02-18 20:47:28.783019: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:874] a: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]]
```

If only tensorflow-gpu is installed but apparently gpu is not being used then how are the results being generated and in the first case how was the gpu detected?
Please advise.

I installed cudnnv 7.0.5 with cuda 9.0 and tensorflow-gpu 1.5

However after rebooting the laptop , it again gives the following :

```
vivek@vivek:~$ python testgpu.py 
/home/vivek/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
2018-02-18 20:52:15.404945: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-02-18 20:52:15.505224: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:895] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-02-18 20:52:15.505734: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1105] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Quadro M1000M major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.0715
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 1.96GiB freeMemory: 1.73GiB
2018-02-18 20:52:15.505770: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1195] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: Quadro M1000M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: Quadro M1000M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0
2018-02-18 20:52:16.920627: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:297] Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: Quadro M1000M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0

MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2018-02-18 20:52:16.923991: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:874] MatMul: (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
b: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2018-02-18 20:52:16.924012: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:874] b: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
a: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2018-02-18 20:52:16.924026: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:874] a: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]]
```

unable to understand what is going on here.