# Setting up tensorflow with GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I followed the [instructions for installing tensorflow with gpu support](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) and I still can't run tensorflow with GPU.
I am using Windows 10. I have CUDA v9.1 installed (verified with nvcc --version), I have NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980M driver, I donwloaded the latest cuDNN installation and placed all the files in the CUDA directory following [these instructions](http://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html). I added the CUDA bin directory to the %PATH$ environment variable, and I made sure I have the %CUDA_PATH% variable defined. I pip installed tensorflow-gpu, and restarted my copmputer. Nothing happens. I still get:

```
Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 ]
```

It might be a path problem. When I pip uninstall tensorflow I get a 'Permission denied' error, because the uninstaller is trying to access my default user, which has a space character in its directory (I know!). But despite this error, tensorflow is still uninstalled.
I tried setting this up with conda but this is not working as well. Conda refuses to acknowledge that I have tensorflow isntalled for some reason.

I read all the online discussions I could find about setting up a GPU and none of them seemed to address this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
After more research it turned out there were three issues: (i) tensorflow is incompatible with CUDA v9.1, and (ii) I had to force removal of cached tensorflow versions and (iii) I had to set the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable. I had to install CUDA v9.0 and also run:

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow
pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow-gpu
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1
```

See [this discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326748/tensorflow-on-gpu-no-known-devices-despite-cudas-devicequery-returning-a-pas)