# Tensorflow can't find GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

My apologies as there's a million questions out there like this, but none of them seem to answer mine. 
I'm trying to re-install Tensorflow so that it uses my GPU.

I'm running:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.6.5
- Keras 2.2.4
- TF 1.13.1
- Nvidia Quadro M1000M (driver 412.16, compute capability 5.0)
- CUDA 10.0.130
- Have CUPTI installed and CuDNN files copied into CUDA folders.

The CUDA v10.0 folder, the \extras\CUPTI\libx64 and the \include folder are all in my PATH, also CUDAPATH is as well as CUDA_PATH is defined)

Yet, with `pip install tensorflow` it only finds my CPU (using:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

And I can't seem to be able to import tensorflow if I

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow-gpu
python
import tensorflow
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer since setting your PATH variables? They do not completely set in until you do a clean restart of your computer.

Comment: Found an answer here after all:
Looks like some leftover modules weren't properly uninstalled. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326748/tensorflow-on-gpu-no-known-devices-despite-cudas-devicequery-returning-a-pas?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tensorflow on GPU: no known devices, despite cuda's deviceQuery returning a "PASS" result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326748/tensorflow-on-gpu-no-known-devices-despite-cudas-devicequery-returning-a-pas)

Comment: sometimes you can have more than one version of TF installed, you have to keep using pup uninstall tensorflow until they are all gone, then use pip install tensorflow-gpu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing Tensorflow again with option --ignore-installed such as:

pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0 --ignore-installed