# My GPUs are not visible with tensorflow-gpu 2.1.0 and CUDA 10.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I am working on Windows 10.

I have installed tensorflow-gpu 2.1.0 and checked that it was in the pip list:

[image]

My python version is 3.7 and CUDA version is 10.1:

[image]

Here is what the nvidia-smi command outpouts:

[image]

As you can see I have 2 GPU's installed and visible with the nvidia command but when I use the command 'tf.config.get_visible_devices()' on my notebook I can only see the CPU:

[image]

Any ideas on how to solve this problem please?

Comment: Your CUDA version is not 10.2.89 -- `nvidia-smi` shows CUDA version 11.0. According to https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements, tensorflow requires CUDA 10.1.

Comment: @jakub That is **incorrect**. `nvidia-smi` shows the CUDA version that your driver supports, not what is installed. I could have no CUDA installed and `nvidia-smi` would still show something.

Comment: Indeed, I had first installed CUDA 11.0 but realized that it wasn't working so I installed CUDA 10.2 then.

Comment: Thanks @ZWang! My mistake.

Comment: @ThomasHustache - can you please try the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48079860/5666087 ? It suggests uninstalling protobuf, tensorfow, and tensorflow-gpu. Then reinstalling tensorflow-gpu.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 2.1.0 is compatible with CUDA `10.1`. Use command `nvcc --version` to verify which CUDA you have installed, and redo the setup if necessary.

Comment: I have CUDA 10.2 which works on another computer but not on the one I am trying to do the setup.

Comment: Then is the correct nvidia-driver for your GPU installed?

Comment: I uninstalled CUDA 10.2 and installed CUDA 10.1 but nothing changed I still can't see the GPU devices with the tensorflow command 'tf.config.get_physical_devices()'. The driver has already been installed before.

Comment: Try `tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')`