# TensorFlow 1.0 and StyleGAN - InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to run [Style GAN](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan) on my laptop with an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 and I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBUFrep8ljI). I am able to generate the .tfrecord files. After that I am trying to run `python train.py` but I am getting the following errors:

```
Building TensorFlow graph...

.... some warnings here

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation G_synthesis_2/lod: {{node G_synthesis_2/lod}} was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:1 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.

.... stack of the errors

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

.... stack of the errors

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation G_synthesis_2/lod: node G_synthesis_2/lod (defined at C:\Users\Acer\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1748)  was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:1 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.
         [[G_synthesis_2/lod]]
```

### I use:

- Windows 10
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650
- Python 3.7.9
- `tensorflow-gpu==1.15`
- CUDA 10.1
- CUDNN 7.65
- Conda virtual environment.

### My Attempts:

1. Check environment variables of CUDA
2. Fix DLL errors
3. Check if GPU is being recognized (yes)
4. Change `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to `0` and `0,1`
5. Uninstall tensorflow and protobuf ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326748/tensorflow-on-gpu-no-known-devices-despite-cudas-devicequery-returning-a-pas))

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: Did you configure the stylegan scripts so it uses only one GPU?

Comment: I didn't configure the stylegan scripts. Moreover, I have only one Nvidia GPU

Comment: That is the problem, you need to configure train.py so it uses only one GPU